# Using the matplotlib to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to analyze the open data,and I tried to plot the scatter figure, but encounter the problem is always show the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 讀入 csv 文字檔
csv_file = ("../ff0002fiac-4.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file,names=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
print(data.head(5))
#df=pd.DataFrame(data)
years=data['a']
people=data['b']
print(years)
print(people)
data.plot(kind='line',x=years,y=people)
plt.show()
```

I expect to show the scatter figure, but the result is error.

Here is the data:

```
a     b       c      d      e      f
0  100  3.56  120905  89608  72562   6686
1  101  3.43  118800  90229  73645   7858
2  102  3.47  116210  90236  73148   9170
3  103  3.17  105977  82889  68020   7949
4  104  3.36  121654  95517  77258  10049
```

and show the error below

KeyError: '[100 101 102 103 104 105 106] not in index'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [pandas.DataFrame.plot documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), the `x` and `y` parameters should be labels or positions. You're probably meaning to do this:

```
data.plot(kind='line',x='a',y='b')
```